# Web Service Imagens Java ZIP Android

Tags: java, android, imagem, arquivo-zip

Preciso que meu aplicativo Android faça o download de uma remessa grande de imagens e armazene no disco do Smartphone, mas preciso decidir qual seria o melhor formato para realizar o download desses arquivos, pois as imagens devem estar disponíveis no modo offline do aplicativo.

1-Web Service retornar um arquivo compactado (zip) com todas as imagens e o aplicativo realizar a descompactação no diretório desejado.

2-???

Comment: Qual a diferença disso e de já enviar as imagens junto com seu APK? Existe algum momento em que elas seriam atualizadas?

Comment: Sim as imagens podem ser atualizadas e/ou incrementadas, acabei não informando no post mas seria um catálogo de produtos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 - Baixe apenas o necessário ao acessar o item requisitado e mantenha-o em cache local. Se existe internet você requisita o item atualizado, caso contrário acesso o item local.

> Perf Theory: Caching - https://youtu.be/JkwrNmCwFfA

3 - Mande a primeira remessa junto junto com seu APK e utilize um `SyncAdapter` para sincronizar os dados entre o dispositivo e o webservice regularmente quando houver internet disponível.

> [Handling Offline Capability and Data Sync in an
>   Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/handling-offline-capability-and-data-sync-in-an-android-app-part-2)

Comment: Excelente, mas vou precisar que seja carregado primeiramente uma remessa completa com todos os arquivos, pois o representante sairá com um catálogo dos produtos e necessitará das imagens previamente carregadas, pois pode ser que não tenha conexão com a internet para realizar o download em tempo de uso.
Mas a ideia de fazer o cache é muito boa, poderia baixar todos em uma remessa via sincronização e atualização e demais operações poderiam ser feitas via cache.

Comment: Ai vai uma terceira opção...

Comment: Gostei dela, vou adaptar o que achei melhor em todas, não posso enviar as imagens com a APK, porque cada empresa terá seu catálogo de produtos, e o cadastro das imagens serão realizados em um site.